# Is it possible to indent a block with no special syntactic meaning?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create an indented block in python?

Consider the following code

```
someCodeHere
try:
   st1
   st2
except Exception:
   pass
otherCode
```

It is indeed indented, but it will have special processing concerning exceptions. In addition I have to provide a useless `except` or `finaly` block containing only `pass`, or `raise` if I do not want to catch the exception

How can I write it as

```
someCodeHere
somethingToAllowIndentationWithoutAnyMeaning
    st1
    st2
otherCode
```

Comment: Disclaimer: this is an almost exact copy from a now deleted question from @PranjalDoshi. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65318809/3545273) for >10k users.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an *empty* context manager to do that:

```
class IndentBlock:
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, typ, vall, track):
        return False
```

It is now possible to write

```
someCodeHere
with IndentBlock():
    st1
    st2
otherCode
```

But having it possible does not mean that is is recommended. **Indentation in Python is known to carry a syntactic meaning**. Above code is indeed correct but IMHO it could upset further readers that would wonder for the rationale for that indentation.